# Very simple web page won't display on IE but will on everything else

Tags: html

I have just started making web pages and I'm having lots of trouble with this very simple web page. I can't make anything appear on IE but it works fine on everyother browser. I'll take the liberty of putting all the code in my question because it is really short. If anyone could help me it would be great!

The html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> <title>Rhaya<title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' media="screen" type="text/css"
href='rhaya.css'/>

</head>
<body>

<div id="masthead"> Rhaya </div>

<div id="content"> Aca va todo el
contenido </div>

<div id="footer"> ©2009 Rhaya | Teresa
Siu | Pía Fabry </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the css is:

```
ul,ol,li {list-style:none}
body {  margin:0 auto; padding:0;font-family: Tahoma;font-size:13px; background: #fff; line-height:15px; color:#000;}
a {color: #000;text-decoration:none}
a:hover {text-decoration:none;color:#000;cursos:default;}

/* Masthead */
#masthead {
    margin:10px 0 10px 0;
    height: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #a2ebf4;
    background-color:#e1f2f9;
    background-image: url(img/header.png);
}

/* Content */
#content {
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size:13px;
}

/* Footer */
#footer {
    clear:both;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #a2ebf4;
    background-color:#e1f2f9;
    text-align:center;
}

 #wrapper{
    width:1002px;
    clear:both;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px auto;
    background:#fff;
}
```

I'm really sorry for asking so blatantly but I really am stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. All you had to do was change the title tag. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a mistake in your html head:

```
<title>Rhaya<title>
```

should be

```
<title>Rhaya</title>
```

Answer (score 10):

For future reference: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input
Use it for resolving html issues.

Comment: Indeed - I was just about to post this :P +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, it actually didn't show up at all in IE.

The reason is that you have the entire page in the title of the page. Change this:

```
<title>Rhaya<title>
```

to:

```
<title>Rhaya</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding the following to you css:

```
div { position: relative; }
```

Comment: While this did not end up being THE solution, only person not familiar with IE6 issues could've marked this down. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html
```

tag isn't closed properly

title tag isn't closed properly.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried and tested. it is your title  problem. enclosed it title /title will definitely work.